# POST form data from third party website to Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I’m hosting a Django website which stores information on users. However, i want to host forms on third party websites e.g. a newsletter signup. I'd like to be able to grab info from a queryset in the URL and post it back to my Django site. I have a small script which grabs the queryset info and places it into a hidden field on the form which then posts that data. However, this is currently done ON my site.

If i were to host the form on someone else’s website, what would be the best way to go about it? Using Ajax? or just changing the action to the full URL of my Django website? Will i have any problems with cross site forgery etc? Ideally Ajax would be better as that way if the users clicks submit, the validation won’t refresh the page and lose the queryset in the URL. Any help would be appreciated :smile:

Comment: You are going to have to remove CSRF Verification on the Django View or you'll get an HTTP Error. 
You might want to consider usgin from **django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt** decorator
If not possible, one work around might be using an iFrame but I've never test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with Ajax. Could you put something like this at the end of your form? in the form you would include the type=post and url where you are posting.

```
$('body').on("submit",'#my_form',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr('action')
    type = $(this).attr('method')


    var username = $('#username').val()
    var email = $('#email').val()


    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: {'username':username,'email':email},
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        error: function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        }
    })
```